# How to retrain a Facenet model with the triplet loss function?

Tags: deep-learning, python, facenet, triplet-loss-function

I want to calculate the similarity or distance of two faces. I'm using Python.

I have read and done what this [tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-face-recognition-system-using-facenet-in-keras-and-an-svm-classifier/) says. However, the result is not good (the similarity of same faces and similarity of different faces are very very very close to each other!).

I have downloaded and used [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PZ_6Zsy1Vb0s0JmjEmVd8FS99zoMCiN1/view?usp=sharing) Facenet model to get face embedding vectors, and then used 3 distance metrics (Euclidean, Manhattan, Cosine) to calculate the distance.

After that, I decided to retrain that Facenet model with my dataset. I read this [article](https://medium.com/@mohitsaini_54300/train-facenet-with-triplet-loss-for-real-time-face-recognition-a39e2f4472c3). I want to use the triplet loss to retrain that Facenet model.

How can I retrain that Facenet model with the triplet loss function? Or can you please send me some links to read?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to train a model that is similar to Facenet, you have to train a Triplet Loss Neural Network similar to the one that you have seen in the tutorial. After training the full network you have to use only a part of the network that is used for embeddings extraction not the whole network, so when you call `model.predict()` you will get embeddings as output.

For more theoretical info, you can refer to Andrew NG lecture about it

For practical part, unfortunately there is no too much but hopefully [this](https://www.kaggle.com/ashishpatel26/triplet-loss-network-for-humpback-whale-prediction) can help at least for building and using the network.